# 'Plugin.Iconize.Fonts.FontAwesomeCollection' threw an exception

Tags: xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I'm trying to use the Xam.Pugin.Iconize.FontAwesome nuget package with my xamarin.forms (shared project) app - targeting Android only. The app compiles fine, but when running the app, I get the following exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Plugin.Iconize.Fonts.FontAwesomeCollection' threw an exception.
```

The exception is thrown at the following line (MainActivity.cs OnCreate method):

```
Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.With(new Plugin.Iconize.Fonts.FontAwesomeModule());
```

No other details about the exception are shown.

I have the following nugets installed (all are the latest versions):

```
Xam.FormsPlugin.Iconize 1.5.0.13-beta
Xam.Plugin.Iconize 2.0.0.37-beta
Xam.Pugin.Iconize.FontAwesome 2.0.0.37-beta
```

My version of xamarin.forms is 2.5.1527436, which is within the required version range required by Iconize (>= 2.3.5 && < 3.0.0).

As per the instructions on the Xam.FormsPlugin.Iconize web page, in my OnCreate(Bundle bundle) method in MainActivity.cs I have set as follows:

```
base.OnCreate (bundle);
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
Plugin.Iconize.Iconize.With(new Plugin.Iconize.Fonts.FontAwesomeModule());
FormsPlugin.Iconize.Droid.IconControls.Init(Resource.Id.toolbar, Resource.Id.tabs);
```

The only version of Xam.Pugin.Iconize.FontAwesome I can get working is the 1.5.0.13-beta release, but this has lots of icons missing from the current FontAwesome collection, so would like to get the latest package working.